# Insert a text document into Mongodb from a REST call

Tags: mongodb, rest

What does it mean to insert a text document into Mongodb from a REST call?

Answer (score 0):

This refers to save the data sent from server using url to mongodb and in order to try it in mongodb use following command

```
db.collection.insert({"id":1,"name":"harish"})
```